# 400, message: "No search query" in Spotify API

Tags: reactjs, api, spotify

> I am trying to obtain a reply (a track list (json)) from the spotify API but I keep getting this error: `{status: 400, message: "No search query"}` this is my function in my spotify.api module:

```js
 search(term) {
 const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
 return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=TRACK&q=${term}`, {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
              },
            }).then(response => {
              return response.json();
            }).then(jsonResponse => {
              if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
                return [];
              }
              return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
                id: track.id,
                name: track.name,
                artist: track.artists[0].name,
                album: track.album.name,
              }));
            });
          },
```

> This is app.js (main container component) where the state is at; these are within the class react constructor:

```
  
    search(term) {
        Spotify.search(term).then(searchResults => {
          this.setState({
            searchResults: searchResults
          })
        })
      }
    
      render() {
        return ( 
        <div> 
           <div className = "App" >
           < SearchBar onSearch={this.search} /> 
            <div className="App-playlist">
            < SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}
            onAdd={this.addTrack} /> 
            < Playlist playlistName={this.state.playlistName}
            playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks}
            onRemove={this.removeTrack}
            onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
            onSave={this.savePlaylist} />
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div>);
      }
    }
```

> This is the searchBar.js component, where the input (or track) will be requested:

```js
search() {
     this.props.onSearch(this.state.term);
   }
 
   handleTermChange(event) {
     this.setState = { term: event.target.value };
   }
 
   render() {
     return (
       <div className="SearchBar">
         <input
           onChange={this.handleTermChange}
           placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist"
         />
         <button className="SearchButton" onClick={this.search}>SEARCH</button>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Post the code where you are calling search function

Comment: What is `term` value. It seems like `term` value is not going in url

Comment: added code as requested

Comment: In the browser's inspector, what's the request you actually see in the network tab, when you click the Search button?

Comment: Spotify.jsx:30 GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q= 400
search @ Spotify.jsx:30
search @ App.js:62
search @ SearchBar.js:17

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this

```js
handleTermChange(event) {
  this.setState = { term: event.target.value };
}
```

To

```js
handleTermChange(event) {
  this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
}
```

Since you were not using the setState method correctly, you were calling the Spotify API with an empty term value, then you get the http 400 error.